# Must custom controls be placed in the App_Code?

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I wrote a custom control inherited from WebControl. (Note: not a user control).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Taopi.WebComponents
{
    public class RatingLabel : WebControl
    {
        public RatingLabel()
            : base("span")
        {        }
        //...
```

I placed it in `/App_Code`, and on a web page it is registered and used as following:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" Namespace="Taopi.WebComponents" %>
...
<uc:RatingLabel Rating='<%# Eval("rating") %>' runat="server" />
```

They run well until I move RatingLabel to  `/Components`, which is folder cerated by me. I got an error saying "*Unknown server tag uc: RatingLabel*" when I try to run the website.

I believe the registration is wrong, so what modification is needed? Must custom controls be placed in the App_Code?

I have another question that where do you usually place your custom controls (except for refering a external DLL)? Are there any "suggested" locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into this before.  The only way I've found you can store code outside of the AppCode folder is to add a "Class Library" project or external DLL as you suggested (which is my preferred approach anyhow as it offers use across multiple projects).

Alternatively, if you use a "Web Application" project type instead of a "Web site" project, you can store code anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. Since the website I'm writing is small, creating another project looks like too laborious. As custom controls must be placed in App_Code, I think it is good to create at least two folders /App_Code/WebControls, which places custom controls and say, /App_Code/Business, which places classes that are needed by code-behind.

Comment: Yes, that would keep it tidier.  However, adding a "Class Library" project is very easy (File/Add/New Project -- Select Class Library type, and then add reference to it from existing project.  You can then reference this project from other websites too.